# Asked to use CCTV to check fellow employee's hours

Tags: colleagues, ethics, united-kingdom, privacy

I am the only employee with access to the CCTV system but I have never been certified in CCTV operation and we do not have a CCTV policy. I inherited it as I am the IT Systems Administrator.

HR have asked me to confirm if an employee was at their station as their overtime form claims.

I feel like this is a violation of their privacy, goes against any code of conduct for CCTV use, is not included as a possibility of monitoring in the Employee Handbook and it compromises my integrity and relationship with fellow employees.

I've raised the concern with my boss and HR but they have sent the request again, this time asking for more details and more dates to check.

Comment: How is it a vioation of their privacy?  They are aware of the cameras are they not?  They are aware that the company might check the records at any time?  Don't say there are not aware of the cameras, you don't work in a building, without that knowlege.

Comment: @Ramhound: well, in my workplace, there are CCTV cams, but their presence is not mentioned in any document or intranet guide. Unless you meant that no one has noticed them?

Comment: @JuhaUntinen - I mean you simply notice them.  This is like saying that the security camera used to prevent employee theft at McD's is a privacy violation.

Comment: General advice questions are off topic here.  What is it you would like to know about or are having difficulty dealing with?  Do you have a link to the Code of Conduct for CCTV use you are talking about?  What specifically do you feel is being violated?

Comment: Are you after actual advice here or looking for someone else to tell you that you're right to refuse?

Comment: What if the boss refused to pay the overtime without proof and the other employee then asked you to look at the CCTV?

Comment: It's clearly not a "privacy" issue whatsoever, though I understand your other concerns.

Comment: "certified in CCTV operation"? Is that even a thing?

Comment: Since there may be legal issues here, you should clarify what country you are in, and possibly what state.  Otherwise, you may get answers that do not match your particular jurisdiction.

Comment: @NathanCooper, as I was much thinking that the ideal could be put into the bosses head..

Comment: @Ian Fair enough. Good point.

Comment: @Ramhound - In France, it is forbidden for a company to check hours of employees with a system which is not for that use. For this to be allowed, the system must have been declared to be for that use and the employees must have been informed.

Comment: It depends on the country. As far as I know, that would be quite illegal in Italy, for instance.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco I wonder if this would be covered by what you suggest. The reason I say this is that the employee has recorded overtime hours using the official timekeeping system (whether that is a punch clock or physical/electronic time card is irrelevant) so the employer has doubts as to whether the employee actually worked. If it is French law that the only way the employer can check on the employee is by using that same system, fraud must be prevalent in France. (i.e. I indicated on my time card I worked 50 hours, so that's what I worked. Boss, you must accept that as fact!)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit There are clearly cultural differences concerning privacy issues, since for me it's quite clear that this is a privacy issue and would most likely be illegal in Germany.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: That's ridiculous.

Comment: I'm no expert in these matters, but AFAIK in Germany surveillance needs to be proportionate, so installing CCTV just to catch time sheet fraud would probably not acceptable since less invasive measures such as checking in/out using a magnet card would work as well. Even if the video surveillance itself is acceptable (e.g. in the public part of a bank), using them to check for time sheet fraud would probably require a concrete suspicion. It's also often necessary to involve employee representatives (Betriebsrat) in such matters. So I wouldn't proceed with this without legal counsel.

Comment: This sounds foul not just because of privacy. For example, if I step out at the time you checked on CCTV and am working offsite, maybe this still is eligible for overtime. If there are questions/concerns HR needs to ask me, not invade my privacy and make assumptions about the claims that I've made in good faith.

Comment: To see why this is privacy issue, consider a similar scenario in the workplace - drug screenings. Some employees must undergo drug screenings as condition for their employment, which may be allowed/agreed upon. HOWEVER suppose HR staff goes into my bathroom to secretly collect urine samples or whatever from my toilet. And then uses this as evidence for drug usage or misconduct or whatever. This is a privacy issue and it is analogous to the CCTV being asked. Major problem is lack of trust. HR needs to come clean and say "hey here's the concern we have" and then go from there.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You tell HR and/or your boss that you have serious doubts about this (your already did) **and** you ask the request in writing (email is fine), backed up by pointers to relevant parts of the Employee Handbook, your contract and/or the law in your country.

You don't have to act confrontational about this, but you have to be firm and get across that you really have a concern that you want to have resolved, and that you want your back covered by a written request in case your concern turns out to be correct.

Note: Depending on law (and legal issues are off-topic here) the presence of the cameras itself may not imply that they can be used for monitoring the employees.

Comment: "ask the request in writing (email is fine)" I agree.

Comment: Right. You should also create a written report in response to these requests. It should state who made the request and when, what camera's recording you looked at and the dates and times you looked at, and what you found. It should also say when you looked at the information. "Per Jack Hammer's request of 07:45EDT September 2, 2014: According to a recording of camera 17A, examined at 08:20EDT on Sept 2, 2014,  George Slacker was at his desk working at 18:45EDT on August 27, 2014 --Dan".

Comment: I'd say "by instruction of" or something similar, rather than just saying that somebody requested the information. To me, that implies that the instruction was non-binding and you had no issues going ahead and filling it.

Comment: I have received advice from an adviser at the Information Commissioner's Office (I'm in the UK). We will not be in breach of the Data Protection Act and I can provide HR with the requested info. I will be handing over all responsibility of the CCTV system to the Facilities Manager and stressing our need for updating the Employee Handbook and creation of our own CCTV Policy to be circulated to staff.

Comment: Since you're in the UK, you may also want to check that the CCTV installation has been correctly registered in accordance with the Data Protection Act.  See the ICO's [CCTV Code of Practice](http://ico.org.uk/for_organisations/data_protection/topic_guides/~/media/documents/library/Data_Protection/Detailed_specialist_guides/ICO_CCTVFINAL_2301.pdf)

Comment: @Alnitak I believe we are not registered correctly. As I said, I've initiated handing over the responsibility to our Facilities manager and given him the relevant info I have been pointed to here.

Answer (score 34):

Let me answer this by asking you another question.

If a co-worker was abused or attacked by a colleague, and they asked you to produce the video of an area at a date and time? Would you comply?

I believe you would.

You should do the same here, because there is no difference.

---

How about if they asked you for the video of a location at a date and time, and *didn't tell you why*. Would you comply then?

---

I work in a bank. We have cameras that are small, and honking large ones. Everywhere.

There is nothing stated in the company policy about cameras. Its obvious that there are cameras around, and if there are, there are people watching.

So it is absolutely reasonable to expect that cameras will be used for monitoring and as well as evidence.

I fear you may be putting your own integrity on the line for a fellow colleague; ignoring any legal complications as they can vary from place to place (and industry to industry); as long as the request is documented and is delivered through the normal, appropriate channels - I do not see anything unreasonable here.

Comment: @Dan: I created a chat room for this. I'll leave it open for a while if anyone is interested in discussion:  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16865/cctv-question-regarding-employee-hours

Comment: Please avoid using comments for extended discussion. Instead, please [get a room, a chat room](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2691/325). Comments are intended to help improve a post. Please see [What "comments" are not...](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-comments-are-not) for more details.

Answer (score 26):

There are clearly legal implications to that request. See for example http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/workplace-cameras-surveillance-employer-rules-35730.html
or http://employment.findlaw.com/workplace-privacy/can-employers-use-video-cameras-to-monitor-workers.html

So it's possible the your boss asks you to do something potentially illegal. 
Hence you should ask your boss and HR for complete indemnification. You have no way of knowing whether the ask is legal and whether your employer has followed all the legal requirements for doing so. So it's perfectly fine to ask (politely, respectfully but insistently) to have written documentation from the employer that states

1. They have followed all relevant legal guidelines for use of CCTV cameras to monitor employee
2. All employees have been properly notified that the monitoring takes place and to what purposes the monitoring is used (and isnt')
3. The company authorizes you to do exactly "insert_very_specific_instructions", nothing more, nothing less
4. Should there be any legal consequences, the company takes full responsibility and completely indemnifies you against any legal recourse from any employee or the company itself

With any luck, this list should scare them off unless they have their act fully together. If they do, you can safely follow through with the request, exactly as outlined in point 3.

Comment: verifying hours worked is unlikely to be ruled illegal

Comment: @Pepone: That very much depends on the country. In Sweden I wouldn't be surprised if it was illegal.

Comment: @Leo well as his an English language site I suspect that 99% of the Q asked are about Anglo-Saxon country's or ex colonies that use English as an official working language.

Comment: @Pepone: It's probably illegal in the UK as well (EU rules on privacy)

Comment: -1 for overreaching in legal advice.

Comment: @Pepone the percentage is definitely not that high, India alone accounts for a solid stream of questions on this site (largely due, I would say, to "unusual" employer/employee dynamics in that country).

Comment: Thank you. Just for clarification, I am in the UK. As I mentioned, I do not believe staff have been notified of the internal surveillance. I have received a follow up request via Email outlining what they require from the footage. I have spoken with an adviser at the Information Commissioner's Office. As there is reason to believe the staff member has provided false documents we should not be in breach of the data protection act. I will be providing it and will giving notice that I will no longer be responsible for the CCTV system and stress that we must create a policy and notify employees.

Comment: @Pepone Please do not assume that users are in a anglo-saxon country, just because SE sites are in English. This is not true at all as large percentage of the user-base are from non-english speaking countries. Many people learn English as a second language. Your 99% are certainly not even close to the true percentage.

Comment: @dirkk so why would anyone sensibly ask for employment advice in a language not used in their country - which is going to exacerbate the problem let alone differences in legal systems most Anglo country's have similar at the core legal systems.

Comment: @Pepone That's why such a country-specific question should be tagged with the specific country. One what ask such a question here, because it is allowed (and also because SE in general is a great place to get answers and also has lot of users which are not in the US or UK). However, if you have questions about this, please ask on meta as this is currently not in-scope of the question.

Comment: @Pepone: [Reality is that less than half the english speakers speak English as their first language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_total_number_of_speakers). Indeed, not all of those will feel like their English is good enough to join the StackExchange, but often it will be and assuming those users are from the US (being the biggest english country by a large margin) is quite short sighted.

Answer (score 13):

As both an IT Director and Security Director for the company I work for, I can tell you that at least in the US this sort of thing is a pretty common requirement for someone in your position. In fact I've even seen retail establishments where they had little or no CCTV coverage of customer areas, but lots of cameras covering employee work areas for just that reason.

Over reporting your hours is a form of fraud, and as such "Employee Handbooks" and other corporate policies and procedures go out the window as far as CCTV and privacy are concerned, because the business is now investigating a potential fraud committed against them.

For the record, I've never actually heard of someone being prosecuted for 'payroll fraud' at any company I've worked for, but I've seen lots of people get fired for it.

The way I look at it, it's one thing if someone is coming in a few minutes late, but when you have people coming in 20 or 30 minutes or even hours late, and claiming the same pay they would earn had they actually worked those hours, it's a crime and the employee should not be surprised if it results in their termination.

In simpler terms, most employees are compensated based on the hours they work. If they are lying about how many hours they are working to get more money than they've actually earned, they are stealing from the company.

So my advice is do what they're asking, because they have every right to ask.

Comment: I'd definitely say this is country-specific. Other countries have far more stringent privacy laws ["Additionally, the Spiegel newspaper printed a list of items from Origin's license agreement it reported could violate German privacy law."](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2011-11-01-ea-denies-origin-spying-on-battlefield-3-users)

Answer (score 5):

**In the UK** (as per the United-Kingdom tag), businesses must explicitly state that employees are being recorded in their contract and signs must be put up.

Additionally you must release CCTV footage to anyone captured on them upon request.

Please see [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/data-protection-your-business/monitoring-staff-at-work)

Comment: "Please see Asked to use CCTV to check fellow employee's hours" - what does this mean? it seems to refer to the very question you're answering, link is http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/33145/asked-to-use-cctv-to-check-fellow-employees-hours

Answer (score -4):

What privacy is violated by using CCTV to check when  they entered  and exited the building the build or are at their  desk or not? Employers do have a right to check up on hours worked and in some country’s not logging  OT hours correctly can get the employer fined.

What code of conduct for CCTV are you referring to?  And its not like you have been asked to look at the content of their email account which would be a privacy violation.

You seem concerned about your relationship with other employees is there a culture of falsifying time sheets at your company – what  I might  term “Spanish” practices.

Just get all HR requests in writing and make sure you conform this with your boss.

Comment: As I said, there is no mention of the cameras in their work area or staff handbook. Obviously I am concerned about my relationship with other employees, who isn't?
All requests from HR and my response have included my Boss as they were via email. I do not know anything about CCTV code of conduct/fair use. That is why i asked the question. Thank you for your response, I needed to see other opinions as I cannot speak to any other members of staff about this issue.

Comment: The legality depends on the law in his country, so your first sentence is just an assumption. You may want to update your answer.

Comment: @Dan why can you not speak either to your boss or HR's legal specialist.

Comment: What privacy would be violated if the CCTV is checked and the employee is nowhere in sight?

Comment: @gnasher729: Depending on the jurisdiction, the privacy of the employee can be considered violated while they are at their place. And if they are not, it is at least a (failed) attempt at doing so, hence no difference (assuming the jurisdiction in question rules out any distinction in punishment for the attempt of an illegal activity and its successful execution).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: well, that's assuming that the employer is attempting to observe the employee in place. Maybe they're trying to observe the employee not in place, or at least can claim to be with a straight face. If that's not an offence, and if they successfully observe that the employee is not in place, is there an inchoate offence or not? At this point the employer calls their lawyer.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Attempting to place video surveillance equipment in non-public places (e.g. areas that only employees can enter), at least without telling everyone concerned, can be an offence in and of itself. In some jurisdictions, footage from surveillance cameras that were installed as a general measure (i.e. not based on a concrete suspicion against a concrete person) is inadmissible as evidence in labor courts to justify firing someone even if an employee is shown stealing property of the company, so I wouldn't expect any better chances if the footage shows the employee being absent.

Comment: @SteveJessop: But this is getting discussion-like an OT, my point is just that whether CCTV can be used at all is *extremely* dependent on the country this happens in.

Answer (score -4):

At least have the common decency to tell the employee that he will be monitored (if you decide to do so).

And contact a lawyer. The indemnification mail mentioned above doesn't work in the jurisdiction where I live, especially not when it should happen to turn out that you get a prison sentence.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to contact the employee who is being targeted by an investigation. That is grounds for termination.