# Invasion of privacy?

Tags: privacy

I'm new here and seeking some advice. Thanks in advance for answers.

I am a city employee here where I live in Tennessee.

A co-worker, who is not an administrator, has gained access to the companies security cameras through his friend in the IT department. He is using this access to log on to the computer at work and his personal PC at home to spy on co-workers and myself to see what we are doing hoping to get us in trouble. I was wondering if this activity is unethical? To make things worse he is the boss's buddy and seems to do no wrong in his eyes. Again, thanks for any and all advice.

Comment: Suggestion, change illegal to unethical.  As this question is presently worded, it is off-topic for The Workplace.  No offense.  I think with some edits this could be made into a good question for the site.

Comment: Related meta: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/82/are-questions-of-law-is-x-legal-questions-off-topic

Comment: I don't think changing illegal to unethical is going to fix this question. In most jurisdictions, this will need legal advice to resolve.

Comment: Related question: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/46908/is-it-okay-to-check-for-employee-attendance-by-means-of-a-security-camera

Comment: @HorusKol we have some really insightful folks providing great answers here every day.  I think they would likely have some good advice regarding this situation if we could take the legality of the act out of the discussion and instead focus on the workplace implications.

Comment: @Lumberjack - the workplace implications are that it is probably illegal, and therefore needs legal advice...

Comment: @HorusKol I respectfully disagree.  If you look at the answers to the related question I linked above you will find a number of quality answers.  One might even argue that this question is a duplicate of that one as it is presently worded....

Comment: @Lumberjack - but then you also link a meta demonstrating that questions of law are unanswerable here due to specific jurisdictions and the fact that we're not lawyers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40031/discussion-between-lumberjack-and-horuskol).

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I guess I should go to HR but have been reluctant to because of the good ole boy system. I completey understand I'm being recorded and of course I'm OK with that, however I wasn't sure it would be OK for anyone to view the cameras as they please for their betterment, especially co-workers not in the administrative branch.

Comment: @lumberjack, it does make me uncomfortable, we work out in the field alot and are usually away from the cameras, however he will go back and check them as we come and go. What got me was I came in one day and went to the restroom. When I came out I went in  the office and he said "I saw you looking at me". At first I didn't know what he was talking about and so explained he saw me looking at the camera when I came out of the restroom (there's a camera in the hallway). That's when I figured out what he was doing. He's been doing it since.

Comment: Can you prove any of this?

Comment: Yes absolutely, I've witnessed it first hand along with another co-worker. He was on them yesterday checking to see if a guy was lieing about something he said he did. Also if the PC has logged everytime he's logged in and pulled the cameras up maybe the head admin could see that?

Comment: If nothing else the guy is wasting time if that is not his job.

Comment: Disgusting. Get out of there ASAP

Comment: It's definitely not his job, him and are both pump techs. Besides this issue I really enjoy my job and the benefits and pay are above average considering where I live. May be an option I'm faced with if the company doesn't handle this issue accordingly. I'm going to get my ducks in a row before I present this to HR. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Well I'm trying to inform myself on state laws and company policies, but I'm definitely taking this problem to HR. I just want to be informed. I was told by a lawyer it was illegal but I should report the situation within the company then go from there.

Answer (score 1):

It is unethical for him. Maybe it is acceptable for the company at large to spy on you and your coworkers, but unless it is explicitly in his job description to conduct surveillance on you, what he is doing to you is unethical and possibly illegal. At the very least that looks like a case of micromanagement.

As what you can do about it, besides consulting a lawyer, or finding a new job (his surveillance can certainly make an employee paranoid) you/your coworkers can tell the HR about his (suspected) activities, safely and discreetly. Then ask for some advice. But be careful. Be certain that they are on your side first. And be careful how you say it. Make sure you do not come across as accusing the administrator of spying or invading your privacy.

Meanwhile, what you can do is to not login any of your personal accounts to your computer. If you already have, log them out and erase the cache. That fellow may hold the information in that against you.

Do not use your company workstation to view sites that had nothing to do with your job, such as confession blogs, dating sites.

If you are a developer or designer, do not visit YouTube with your workstation, even to watch tutorials. Those kind of fellows tend to assume that you're watching non-work-related videos.

Do not search for terms that had nothing to do with your work using your workstation. The administrator might use the search information to advance his agenda.

Log out this account of yours from the same workstation.

View your personal accounts out of reach of the cameras. Do it outside the building if you have to.

Check out the questions posted in the comments as well.

Comment: Its also unethical (and gross misconduct) for the person that gave this person unauthorized access